# Spark: Create per item windowing function

Tags: apache-spark

Lets say I have this data

```
User | Item | Timestamp
A       1         1
A       2         2
B       3         3 
B       4         4
```

I need to group together rows belonging to each user & all events that happened within 1 hours of each event. So basically something like

`groupBy(user, timestamp - 1.hour)`

Is there a way to do this in Spark using RDD? Using Dataframe is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can group by any key you create using:

```
def groupBy[K](f: (T) ⇒ K)(implicit kt: ClassTag[K]): RDD[(K, Iterable[T])]
```

For example:

```
rdd.groupBy { case (user, timestamp, otherData) => (user, timestamp - 1.hour) }
```

The simpler the keys, the better. Occasionally, using `String` keys works better so you can group by

```
s"$user/${timestamp - 1.hour}"
```

The best case is that you can build unique `Int` or `Long` keys using some fast domain-specific logic.